# Spring MVC 5, Wildfly and Log4J2

Tags: spring-mvc, wildfly, log4j2

I'm trying to understand how to set up my application (with Spring MVC 5) to log with Log4J2 on Wildfly 15.

On Wildfly I've excluded the module org.apache.logging.log4j in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml like this:

```
 <deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

After that it seems that Wildfly is using log4j2 to log (because I can see in console a lot of line breake like log4j2 does).
The problem is that Spring probably has an inner log4j2 config because ignore any config I put on log4j2.properties or log4j2.xml.

This is the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Yes, Spring has its own version of log4j and I've found it in the MyBatis-Spring library. I resolved the issue excluding that library.

If you are using Eclipse, I suggest to use it's Dependency Hierarchy view for the pom.xml which shows all the libraries included with your imports.